# Como fazer autenticação via cabeçalhos e acessar API

Tags: javascript, auth

O acesso às API's deverá ser feito passando os seguintes dados no header da requisição:

`"[{"key":"chave-api-dados","value":"123456789"}]`

Por favor! Onde adiciono esses valores para autenticação e ter acesso a API?

```
function buscarPorCpf(){

    const cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
    const mesAno = buscaMes();
    const url = "http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-disponivel-por-cpf-ou-nis?codigo="+cpf+"&anoMesReferencia="+mesAno+"&anoMesCompetencia="+mesAno+"&pagina=1";

    var ajax = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

    if (!ajax) {
      throw new Error('CORS not supported');
    }
  

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        if (this.responseText.length < 3) {  
        $('#dados2').hide();   
        $('#novaconsulta').show();
          }
            let resposta = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0];
            const valor = resposta.valor;
            const nome = resposta.titularBolsaFamilia.nome;
            const cpf = resposta.titularBolsaFamilia.cpfFormatado;
            
            document.getElementById("pcpf").innerHTML = cpf;
            document.getElementById("pessoas").innerHTML = nome;
            document.getElementById("pvalor").innerHTML = valor;



    }


};

    ajax.send();



}


function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
      xhr.open(method, url, true);

  
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);

  
    } else {
  
      xhr = null;
  
    }
    return xhr;
  }
```

Comment: vc incluiu a sua chave na pergunta anterior e fiz um teste e ela não é válida. Verifica se está correta e faça um teste em http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/swagger-ui.html. Deverá ser preciso solicitar o desbloqueio conforme http://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/cadastrar-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader), pode-se adicionar headers aos pedidos http fazendo: `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(header, value)`.

O método deve ser usado depois de `open` e antes de `send`.

Já `XDomainRequest` não tem um método semelhante.

Assim sendo, e considerando-se que o `XDomainRequest` já praticamente não é mais suportado, poderia-se remover o trecho de código que faz referência ao mesmo e fazer `ajax.setRequestHeader("chave-api-dados", sua_chave)` antes da sua linha `ajax.onreadystatechange (...)`.

Comment: tentei fazer suas alterações no código e continua sem autorização, poderia nos dar o exemplo como ficaria o código?

Comment: @Igor vc incluiu a sua chave na pergunta anterior e fiz um teste e ela não é válida. Verifica se está correta e faça um teste em http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/swagger-ui.html. Deverá ser preciso solicitar o desbloqueio conforme http://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/cadastrar-email

Comment: a minha chave está correta, porém não postei a chave correta aqui, você pode postar aqui como ficou o código depois que editou? Obrigado.

Comment: Consegue fazer um teste em portaltransparencia.gov.br/swagger-ui.html?

Comment: Sim eu fiz o teste, minha chave está liberada, o erro que tenho agora é `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/bolsa-familia-disponivel-por-cpf-ou-nis?codigo='00000000000&anoMesReferencia=202101&anoMesCompetencia=202101&pagina=1' from origin 'http://uni5.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Neste caso @Igor, o pedido já está sendo bloqueado pelo navegador, pq a API não tem uma política para aceitar pedidos de qualquer site, o que significa que vc não pode fazer o pedido diretamente pelo Front end. Uma alternativa é usar um proxy. Tenta trocar o endereço da api para https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/(endereço antigo com http://)

Comment: funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Igor, já que conseguiu confirmar que é esse o problema, recomendo ter um proxy próprio. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma googlada para achar qual método da classe `XMLHttpRequest` adiciona headers (cabeçalhos) à requisição HTTP que vai ser feita. Headers são pares de strings: um é a chave ou nome do header, o outro é o valor.

Chame esse método no objeto `xhr` passando a chave e o valor como argumentos.

**Edit:** Achei para você:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("chave-api-dados", "123456789")
```

Voilà!

Comment: adicionei o código depois do ```xhr.open(method, url, true);``` porém retorna o erro ```net::ERR_FAILED``` poderia nos dar um exemplo de como ficaria o código?

Comment: Mano, só dei a dica, não mexo com JavaScript. Acho que o problema do header foi resolvido e a requisição foi enviada, porém o envio falhou devido a algum erro de rede. Tem que pesquisar para ver o que pode ser. Uma possibilidade é esses `this.readyState` e outros `this` que você está chamando dentro da função que trata a resposta do Ajax na verdade serem `ajax.readyState`, etc. Não tenho certeza. Dê uma pesquisada, aceite esta resposta se lhe atendeu e se for o caso crie uma nova pergunta.